How to use local variables in nested verbs?
Perhaps there's no facility to do this in the J language, but when I write:
succession =: monad define
  greg =. 1 2 3
  tom =. {{ greg }}
  tom y
)

and then call succession 'season 1', I get the following error:
|noun result was required: tom
|       greg

My understanding is that the variable greg is not available in the namespace of the nested verb tom, and so greg is assumed to be a verb. But verbs can't be returned as values from verbs, hence the error.
Two unsatisfactory solutions come to mind:

Add greg to the global environment using =: instead of =.. This is of course horribly error-prone.
Pass greg as the left argument to tom. This seems ugly/unnecessary, and it gets even messier if tom eventually requires access to more local variables (kendall, shiv, roman).


you are correct that there is no good way to do this; j does not have closures
my style is to make nested definitions tacit wherever possible, which does avoid this problem
if you are going to use locales, i would suggest not to use named locales, but rather create a fresh locale and pass it in, viz.
succession =: monad define
  l=. cocreate''
  greg__l=. 1 2 3
  tom=. l&{{ greg__x }}
  tom y
)

but do note that you now have to delete the locale at some point; there is no such problem when you pass in a context array

Aren't locales GCed?

HAHAHAHA!  nope.

I believe a sane solution is to use an appropriate namespace:
t =: monad define
 greg_loc_ =. 1 2 3
 tom =. {{ greg_loc_ }}}
 tom y
)
t 'hi'
1 2 3


"Private assignment is not used for locatives, which are always public in their locale.", cited from: https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/eqdot4 . So, it's global, indeed.

I take it that OP is concerned about exposing the variables and not about memory management or efficiency. Namespaces are, of course, always global.
